# I am using ngx-bootstrap datepicker if i type a number, its automatically formatiing

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular6, bootstrap-datetimepicker, ngx-bootstrap

I am using  bootstrap date picker  if i type a number, its automatically formatting(force parse).
 So,how can i false "force-Parse" in  *bootstrap*  date picker. if i'm giving four digit  or five digit(**11111**)when focus-out its automatically formatting like "**11/11/0001**".so i'm want to disable force-parse.
If i'm giving two digits also its accepting and make format like that.

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 box">
    <div class="datepicker" style="display:inline-block;position:relative;">
            <input style="width: 312px;" class="changebg" 
            [maxDate]="maxDate"
            id="dateOfBirth"
            [(ngModel)]="user.dob"
            name="dob"
            #dob="ngModel"
            #dpYMD="bsDatepicker"
            bsDatepicker
            [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD' }"
            required>
            <div [hidden]="dob.valid || dob.pristine" class="alert text-danger">
                <div [hidden]="!dob.hasError('required')">DOB is required</div>
            </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

At this time there is no way to set the strict date parse for the bsDatepicker.

What I did as a workaround is that I listen on input change event and remember the last valid date input from the user. Then on the input `(change)="onChange($event)"` I reset the formControl value for the input manually with the last valid date value.

```
@HostListener('input', ['$event.target.value', '$event'])
onInput(value: string, event: any): void {
    if (this.dateInputFormat) {
        const parsedDate = moment(value, this.dateInputFormat, true);
        if (parsedDate.isValid()) {
            this.lastValidDateValue = parsedDate.toDate();
        } else {
            this.lastValidDateValue = null;
        }
    }
}

onChange(event: Event): void {
    const target = (event.target as HTMLInputElement);
    if(this.lastValidDateValue) {
        const parsedDate = moment(this.lastValidDateValue).format(this.dateInputFormat);
        this.dateValue = this.lastValidDateValue;
        target.value = parsedDate;
        this.formControl.patchValue(this.dateValue);
    } else {
        target.value = undefined;
        this.dateValue = null;
        this.formControl.patchValue(null);
    }
    
    this.formValidators && this.formControl.setValidators(this.formValidators);
    this.formControl.updateValueAndValidity(); 
}
```